# Magento 2: How to get search products Collection

Tags: magento2.3, product-collection, catalogsearch

I need to get search products collection in .phtml. Currently i'm getting but Bundle products are missing. I want custom search collection.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In which phtml file?

Comment: list.phtml file

Comment: have u done any customisation? in list page bundle products are not showing?

Comment: Ensure that status of the product is 'enabled' and visibility is 'catalog, search' and that you have selected a store on the 'websites' tab of the product if you are using multiple store config.

Comment: I wrote a collection for bundle products but I need search results also

Answer (score 0):

view.phtml

`$block->getLayer()->getProductCollection();`

In case you want to view in another phtml file one of the ways is to create Helper for this. The class to call is
`\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver`

method:

```
$layer = $this->layerResolver->get();

$layer->getProductCollection();
```